# my index.cgi does not run instead it only prints its content

Tags: cgi

I want to run an index.cgi in my front end directory rather than an index.html. However the script does not run and only prints out the script in text.  I am on running apache2 on ubuntu 18.04.  What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to follow one of the Apache CGI tutorials, e.g.

- https://code-maven.com/set-up-cgi-with-apache
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html

(Google for "apache cgi tutorial" for more)